# How to set the default font of SwiftUI.Text?

Tags: swiftui

[image]

If I do not want to type like `Text("Hello world").font(.anuRegular(14))`, I want just `Text("Hello world)`, How to custom default font for Text?

Answer (score 11):

You can set the default font for your entire SwiftUI app by using the Environment modifier and setting the .font key to the desired font.

```
WindowGroup {
    ContentView()
        .environment(\.font, Font.custom("CustomFont", size: 14))
}
```

If you want to use a different font for a specific Text view, you can still override the default by applying a different font modifier to that view. If you will not override, default font will be the custom font.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a custom View:

```
struct TextLabel: View {//any name you like excluding Text & Label.
    let text: String
    init(_ text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .font(.anuRegular(14))
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this name conflict with the default [`Label`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/label)? I suppose it might not because it doesn't have generics.

Comment: Oh yes you're right, it does!